# How to add paragraph symbol

Tags: mac, pages

I send a friend w/o a Mac some paragraphs & they disappear in the sending, so I'd like to include the paragraph symbol at the start of each paragraph so she can see where they go. How do I do that in Pages 5.2.2 on a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable "Show Invisibles" from `View > Show Invisibles` or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to see these "invisible" characters in Pages. These are *invisibles* that appear when the selection highlight goes over their area, and disappear when unhighlighted. For identification purposes they're usually colored blue.

To add a *non-invisible* paragraph symbol (or any other delimiter of your choice), <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should bring up a "Characters" window, from which you can double-click on any character to add it to the current text field.

The characters under this window follow their [Unicode](http://unicode.org) specification, so some names might seem a little *weird* (e.g. "Place of Interest Sign" for "⌘").  The name for the Paragraph symbol is "Pilcrow".

Answer (score 0):

With the US keyboard layout, you can make the ¶ sign with the key combination <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>.